# How do I select a column using an alias

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

How do I perform an sql query such as this?

`SELECT column_name AS alias_name FROM table_name;`

Example: I want the column 'first' to be selected as 'firstname'

```
Table.findAll({
      attributes: [id,"first"]
    })
    .then(function(posts) {
        res.json(posts);
    })
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
Table.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['first', 'firstName']] //id, first AS firstName
})
.then(function(posts) {
  res.json(posts);
});
```

Comment: It works, but when used in a join query, it appends the table name to the alias given. Is there a way to remove the table name?

Comment: @antew you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148491/how-to-get-join-data-result-without-prefix-table-name-in-sequelize-orm

Comment: It doesn't work in multi-level joins. Lets say, Table A includes ( Table B  includes Table C ). I cannot select Table C columns in Table B ( it always prefixes table A )

Answer (score 4):

**You need to use `row.get('newname')` to access columns aliased by `attributes`**

Doing just `row.newname`, or `row.oldname`, will not work like it does for non-aliased names for some reason:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10592
- https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html documents it:

  ```
  Project.findOne({
    where: {title: 'aProject'},
    attributes: ['id', ['name', 'title']]
  }).then(project => {
    // project will be the first entry of the Projects table with the title
    // 'aProject' || null
    // project.get('title') will contain the name of the project
  })
  ```

  but [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html) doesn't mention it, which is confusing:

  ```
  instance.field
  // is the same as
  instance.get('field')
  ```

Related: [Sequelize cannot access alias. Alias is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681000/sequelize-cannot-access-alias-alias-is-undefined)

Minimal runnable example:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
});
(async () => {
const Int = sequelize.define('Int', {
  value: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
}, {});
await Int.sync({force: true})
await Int.create({value: 2, name: 'two'});
let row;
row = await Int.findOne({
  where: { value: 2 },
  attributes: [ 'id', [ 'value', 'newvalue' ] ],
});
assert.strictEqual(row.id, 1);
assert.strictEqual(row.value, undefined);
assert.strictEqual(row.newvalue, undefined);
assert.strictEqual(row.get('newvalue'), 2);
await sequelize.close();
})();
```

The generated query does exactly what we wanted then:

```
SELECT `id`, `value` AS `newvalue` FROM `Ints` AS `Int`
  WHERE `Int`.`value` = 2 LIMIT 1;
```

tested on sequelize 6.5.1, sqlite3 5.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

Also Sequelize supports defining column names directly on the model definition too.

[Sequelize Docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#column-options) On that they mention about `field` attribute on column definition.

ex: (Taken from Docs itself)

```js
const { Model, DataTypes, Deferrable } = require("sequelize");

class Foo extends Model { }
Foo.init({
    // You can specify a custom column name via the 'field' attribute:
    fieldWithUnderscores: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING, 
        field: 'field_with_underscores'
    },
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'foo'
});
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963516/is-there-no-option-to-map-the-column-name-in-sequelize-model)

Answer (score 0):

As Jan Aagaard Meier, this can be done.

```
Table.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', ['first', 'firstName']] //id, first AS firstName
})
.then(function(posts) {
  res.json(posts);
});
```

But sometimes, it can be tiring to list all attributes just to rename one or two and everytime a model changes, the code needs to be changed to.

So inorder to rename or alias few columns without defining all attributes, use ***include***

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('hats')), 'n_hats']
    ]
  }
});
```

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#specifying-attributes-for-select-queries