# How do I select a value as a column in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do I perform sql query such as this `SELECT 'OLD'  AS CUSTOM_COLUMN FROM TABLE` in sequelize?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select a column using an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649218/how-do-i-select-a-column-using-an-alias)

Answer (score 4):

You can use ***sequelize.literal*** for that.

```
const response = await YourModel.findAll({
        where: {
            ...attributes
        },
        attributes: [
            'column_name_on_model',
            [sequelize.literal("'OLD'"), 'CUSTOM_COLUMN'], //custom column name
        ],
        raw: true
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you've set up a model for your table, you can alias the column in the model definition:

```
{
  CUSTOM_COLUMN: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     field: 'OLD'
  }
}
```

And then limit a find query to that column:

```
MyModel.find all({ attributes: ['CUSTOM_COLUMN'] })
```

(See http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/models-definition/)