# Sequelize cannot access alias. Alias is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

aliasName: -1

The value of aliasName is -1.

[image]

aliasName: undefined

aliasName is giving me undefined.
[image]

Comment: `likess`? Two `s`s? You seem to have been consistent, so it should work, just checking.

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML rather than the rendered web page?

Comment: Yes, because the normal column is named likes so I just put two s for the other one.

Comment: Also when I do console.log(posts[0].likess); in nodejs its returning undefined for some reason. I think its an alias problem in sequelize. I cannot access alias for some reason. When I use alias  "likess".
[models.sequelize.fn('sum', models.sequelize.col('likes')), 'likess']]

Comment: what is the console log for: `console.log(posts);` in your code?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Did this and worked.

posts[0].get('aliasName')

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Added some documentation mentions of this at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649218/how-do-i-select-a-column-using-an-alias/69890944#69890944 now.